# signed or unsigned int in c++

Tags: c++, std, unsigned, signed

How can i check if given int(or any other data type) is signed or unsigned?
I found this function while searching,

```
std::numeric_limits<int>::is_signed
```

But i can only input the data type, is there a way that i can check by variable name, like.

```
signed int x = 5;
```

Now i want to make a function which checks that x is a signed int or not.

And if you guys can answer these little questions, that would be highly appreciated.

1. Why do we use '::' these operators after std?
2. What do they mean when we use them in std::cout, is it the same?
3. Here numeric_limits<> is a class or what?
4. And again, why are we using these '::' before is_signed?

Comment: One question per post, please.

Comment: For your question about '::' you can search on google 'namespace operator in c++'

Comment: `::` is *scope resolution operator*, to be exact.

Comment: How does the function not know whether `x` is signed or not? Is it a function template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way that i can check by variable name

Since C++11, we have `decltype` to get the type of a variable or expression:

```
std::numeric_limits<decltype(x)>::is_signed
```

Historically, it was trickier; the only way to infer a type from a variable was through template argument deduction:

```
template <typename T>
bool is_signed(T const &) {
    return std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed;
}
```

> Why do we use '::' these operators after std?

That's the *scope resolution* operator, saying that we want the name `numeric_limits` to be looked up in the namespace `std`.

> What do they mean when we use them in `std::cout`, is it the same?

Yes. Like most names in the standard library, `cout` is also scoped inside `namespace std`.

> Here `numeric_limits<>` is a class or what?

It's a class template, containing various static variables and functions that describe the type used as the template argument. Here's a reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits

> And again, why are we using these '::' before is_signed?

Again, that resolves the scope by saying we want the name `is_signed` to be looked up inside the class scope of `std::numeric_limits<int>`.

Comment: C++98 can also do better and get a compile-time constant out of it: `boost::is_signed<BOOST_TYPEOF(x)>::value`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
constexpr bool is_signed = std::numeric_limits<decltype(x)>::is_signed();
```

This will fail to compile if there's no specialization of `numeric_limits` for the type of `x`, though. A more generic solution would be `is_signed` from `<type_traits>` header:

```
constexpr bool is_signed = std::is_signed<decltype(x)>::value;
```

And yes, both are `numeric_limits` and `is_signed` are class templates.